# How do I set up an ad in Google DFP that can be included in an email newsletter?

Tags: html-email, google-dfp

I'd like to include a few ad spots in my newsletter and I think Google DFP can be used to managed ads in emails. The code that it generates requires Javascript which I can't include in my HTML email template. **How do I set up the ad in Google DFP and how do I generate the code to display the ad in my HTML email?**

Answer (score 1):

Since email coding is limited to XHTML 1.0, your options are limited. I'll be honest, DFP is a really, really bad platform for serving ads in email. I manage a team that sends out ~2B emails per year for a large lifestyle media company and it's been a challenge for us simply because it's such a manual process. There are really good alternatives in the space if your needs merit a specialized solution.

If you're not sending a lot of volume it is achievable (albeit hacky). Like you eluded to in your question - email is not capable of utilizing JavaScript so you're limited to straight HTML through an image request and no-script beaconing. You'll need to leverage a 1x1 with query parameters to designate the newsletter name, ad type, brand or whatever else you wish to track.

Here is a rough example:

```
<a href="http://adserver.yoursite.com/clicktracker.ng/site=yoursite&newsletter=03_10_15_Yourbrand&ad=Big_Box&issue=315">
<img src="ad_creative/ESP redirect" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="advertisement">
</a>
```

You'll need a standard image tag that uses key-values to target the ad to the newsletter you'll be publishing on. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm interested to hear of a good alternative to DFP for email banners also.